# AngularJS limitTo filter for ngRepeat on an object (used like a dictionary)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

Is it possible to use `limitTo` filter on a `ngRepeat` directive which is repeating the properties of an Object and not items in an Array.

I am aware that the official documentation says that the input to `limitTo` needs to be an array or a string. But wondering if there's a way to get this to work.

Here's a sample code:

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, item) in phones_dict |orderBy:'-age'| limitTo:limit_items"></li>
```

And `$scope.phones_dict` is an Object like

```
{ 
     item_1: {name:"John", age: 24},
     item_2: {name:"Jack", age: 23}
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

limitTo works only for strings and arrays, for object use own filter for example:

```
myApp.filter('myLimitTo', [function(){
    return function(obj, limit){
        var keys = Object.keys(obj);
        if(keys.length < 1){
            return [];
        }

        var ret = new Object,
        count = 0;
        angular.forEach(keys, function(key, arrayIndex){
            if(count >= limit){
                return false;
            }
            ret[key] = obj[key];
            count++;
        });
        return ret;
    };
}]);
```

Example on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wk0k34na/2/

Comment: The caveat here is that iterating over the keys in an Object does not have guaranteed order so using this may not make sense, since you *may* see different results each time

Comment: true, orderBy also works only in arrays. On obj. you have to also create own object filter. I expand my example in http://jsfiddle.net/wk0k34na/3/ so the order is also another filter.

Answer (score 10):

Adding

```
 ng-if ="$index < limit"
```

to the ng-repeat tag did the trick for me, though it's probably not strictly the "right" way to do this.

Comment: This works great. filter('myLimitTo' is also working but is throwing some anonymous errors.

Comment: Work likes a charm. limitTo didn't work. I tried many methods but this is the one did the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use 'track by $index'... And your limitTo would be:

```
limitTo: $index == 5 (or any value)
```

Comment: This did not work:
`<li ng-repeat="(key, item) in phones_dict track by $index | limitTo: $index == 5"></li>`

Comment: @YogeshMangaj - track by $index needs to go at the end of the ng-repeat, so <li ng-repeat="(key, item) in phones_dict | limitTo: $index == 5 track by $index"></li>

Comment: That did not work for me. Still getting every object in my json file instead of just 5.

Comment: @OamPsy : I am also looking for a similar solution. Please help

Comment: @Ricky <tr ng-repeat="result in results | filter:artiste | limitTo:20">

Comment: AngularJS' `limitTo` filter will not work when input is an object (only works against Array, string, or number -- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo), AND `limitTo` filter's first parameter should be a number/string (not a boolean condition), AND even in the weird scenario you used `$index` it would be zero-based!

Answer (score 0):

Default limitTo filter has support for array-like objects ([example](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/b03957f0047fcfe996abc8efe97f9e2be2c2e13a#diff-a8d2ffdbd30cae94b967ed5a67c965e1R14)) after [1.5.7](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#157-hexagonal-circumvolution-2016-06-15)