# Can ng-repeat limitTo be applied to repeat on json instead of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am doing an ng-repeat on a json object based on it's keys.
Now I am able to limit the no of repeated items to say 5 using ng-repeat="item in array|limitTo:5" for an array object.

But when I try doing ng-repeat="key in json|limitTo: 5" its not succeeding in restricting the number of repeats what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom filter to handle a json object:

```
app.filter('limitTo', function () {
    return function (jsonItems, limit) {
        var lengthJson = Object.keys(jsonItems).length;
        if (lengthJson<=limit)
            return jsonItems;
        else
        {
            var slicedJsonItems = {};

            //your slicing algorithm here to limit the length

            return slicedJsonItems;
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As we see from the documentation:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo

The input is limited to: Source array, string or number to be limited.

You can build your own filter to make this limit.

For more info look at: [AngularJS limitTo filter for ngRepeat on an object (used like a dictionary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25868760/angularjs-limitto-filter-for-ngrepeat-on-an-object-used-like-a-dictionary)

Besides this, what is the reason to use the limitTo filter on an object when you cannot control the order? An array would be better here.

Comment: I am receiving a json object from a backend java application and was ng-repeating on it as it is. So converting it into an array for the sake of limiting the number of displayed items would be an added overhead.

Comment: It is an overhead, but compared to the time you wait for the ajax it is not recognizable. When you change it to an array you can also control the order of the results. So the customers won't ask you why they get every time for the same data different results