# How to display limited data using Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have seen enough examples on how to display the limited results using `limitTo`. But unfortunately it isn't working as expected. Currently, it is displaying the entire list but I want to limit it to only 8 key,value items in 4/4 blocks.

Here is the [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZlOQC9A4FZWZfowSMZee?p=preview).

```
  <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in stocks |limitTo :8">
            {{key +" "+ value}}
      </li>
  </ul>

 <script>
    var app = angular.module('smallcaseApp', []);
    app.controller('stockCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("data.json").then(function(response) {
        $scope.stocks = response.data.price;
      });
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Add a plunker that works. Yours is not working.

Comment: It is updated. Check it please.

Comment: As per the docs over here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo, the input type can be `Array/array-like, string or number`. It does not work with the js object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For limitTo input should be either array or string/number. You need to create custom filter to handle it. Here's working plunk for your issue

```
app.filter('objLimitTo', [function(){
return function(obj, limit){
    if(obj){
      var keys = Object.keys(obj);
      if(keys.length < 1){
        return [];
      }
    }

    var result = {},
    count = 0;
    angular.forEach(keys, function(key){
        if(count >= limit){
            return false;
        }
        result[key] = obj[key];
        count++;
    });
    return result;
};
}]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/8d3gUqg4vHeGQWUXYrat?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

First of all your plunkr is not working, angular js link should be above any other js (your app js).

You are iterating in a `Object`, for using limitTo here there's already a working good example, please take a look [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25869639/2293313)